# The best way to sandbox programs in OSX?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, sandbox

I know that this question have been discussed before on AskDifferent, but none of the threads really satisfied me. For Windows you have a wonderful program called Sandboxie http://www.sandboxie.com/ that let you easily set up sandboxes with different rules and  privileges. What is the eaisest and most secure way of sandbox *really malicious* programs?

Comment: "most secure way of sandbox really malicious programs?” Run a virtual machine.

Answer (score 3):

> easiest and most secure way

Please choose A or B, not both.

> *really malicious* programs

Are we talking invasive virus software, like the stuff that came on Sony CDs?

Either a carefully-configured virtual machine, like VMware Fusion, or an isolated physical machine. By "isolated" I mean not used for anything else and not connected to any network. Make a fresh install of the OS, do what you need, but then never use the machine for anything else. I would assume that "really malicious" software would modify the recovery partition, bootloader, and even the firmware.

Answer (score 0):

Prepare a version of OS X that  installs from a USB drive or a DVD-ROM.
 Set up a virtual machine for instance using Parallels or VirtualBox and run the malicious software inside the virtual machine.